# How to force a user to grant extended permissions on a page tab app?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am making a page tab app that requires certain user extended permissions to function how I want it to.

I use both the PHP and the JavaScript SDK, and the first thing I tried was a simple `FB.login()`, listing the scope, including the extended permissions. The problem is that the user can log in and enter my app successfully even if he declines the extended permissions. After this, I redirect the user back to the login page to ask for the permissions again, but from here on, every call to `FB.login()` makes the popup appear and then disappear right away, let the user into my script that checks the permissions and kicks the user back to the login page again; which means `FB.login()` doesn't ask for permissions at all if all the mandatory permissions are already granted, even if extended permissions aren't.

With this app, outside of facebook, I could do `$facebook->getLoginUrl()`, passing the needed extended permissions, and redirecting the user to the external, facebook login form. Therem facebook does try to ask for the missing extended permissions, and if the user declines, he will be taken back to the login page, where this can repeat until the user does finally grant the permissions, or leaves the site. This is good, this works.

The problem is, my app in reality, resides in a page tab, and there, like I said, the `FB.login()` method doesn't work either way, redirecting the user to the Facebook login form within the IFrame doesn't seem to work at all (I seem to be redirected right back to the same page without a chance to see the facebook.com external login form in the IFrame of facebook :P), and I also tried redirecting the whole page (not just the IFrame) with `window.top.location.href = loginUrl`, where loginUrl has the url to the page tab within facebook (generated by `$facebook->getLoginUrl($params)`), but in that case, I am completely redirected to another facebook area, but it shows the error about the redirect_uri not being owned by the app, which is true, because the redirect uri has facebook.com in it, just pointing to the tab where my app is.

So I found no way of being able to keep asking the user for the needed extended permissions in the case of a page tab app. Does anyone know how I can get what I want to work? Like is there a way to force the `FB.login()` dialog to ask for extended permissions, like it doesn't do by default?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has engineered it so extended permissions are no longer mandatory.
This, unfortunately, means you cannot force the user to accept them.

A good way to handle it would be to let the user login to the app and then have a prompt telling the user what they are missing out on by not allowing the permissions and prompt them again to accept.
If they still don't accept then present them with a nice 'Sorry, you cannot use this app till you accept the permissions' page

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Extended_Permissions/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/

Comment: I know they aren't mandatory, but prompting the user again is where I'm having problems.

I'm having trouble prompting a user to accept the extended permissions if the user had already already accepted the basic permissions earlier.

Please read through my question post.